# Two index increment in for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, time-complexity

While reading a text on loop analysis, I came across the following linear search routine to return the maximum value in an array:

```
template <class otype>
int location_of_max (const otype a[], int first, int last)
{
    int max_loc = first; 
    for (++first; first <= last; ++first) {
        if (a[first] > a[max_loc]) {
            max_loc = first;
        }
    }

   return max_loc;
}
```

Having two increments `++first` in the same loop condition is a bit confusing. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code compares two elements on each loop.

The initial loop declaration statement is advancing the "start" iterator to the second array position, because the "reference" element (`a[max_loc]`) begins life as the first element.

This avoids one unnecessary and meaningless comparison (i.e. `a[max_loc] > a[max_loc]`).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at what it is doing.

1. Initialize max_loc to the first index.

The format of a for loop is ( init; condition; increment ).

At this point there is no need to check if a[first] > a[max_loc] because first == max_loc, so as part of init first is pre-incremented to the next index. This step is only executed once. The second increment happen on every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score -3):

The first clause in the **for** statement is just a starting value, executed only once, before the block executes.

The third clause is executed at the end of each block iteration, and just before the condition - second clause - is evaluated.

Comment: OP is asking _why_ the initialisation statement is written this way. Not what a `for` loop does.